# Converting dwg file by GISpoint

Tags: arcgis-desktop, csv, excel

I am working with an excel/csv file which contain Easting Northing & Elevation value (Its all about point feature). But when i am converting this file in dwg by GIS for use in auto cad then the elevation value is not showing in cad only point feature is showing.

How would I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Esri's How To: Retain elevation values when converting from a shapefile to CAD](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008886) states, you will need to add a field named "Elevation" to your feature class (type = double). The values in it will be available in the "Elevation" field of the dwg file.

Comment: Dear sir, I have tried it several times but in Auto CAD it's not showing it's elevation value.

Comment: Actually it is not showing on the top of the point in Auto CAD but showing Easting, northing & elevation below the command bar. i need the value top of the points.

Comment: @TK Bala This is more like a follow-up question regarding AutoCAD. Unfortunately I'm no expert in AutoCAD and therefore cannot help you.